# Why Uri.TryCreate return TRUE for Uri like mail:foo?

Tags: c#, asp.net, uri

why using method `Uri.TryCreate` I get BOOL TRUE if the URI is not in Uri.Schema??.

Here the Uri.Schema from MSDN:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.scheme.aspx

Try for example a string `"mail:foo"` it return True and I do not understand why.

Any ideas? Maybe a bug in MS framework or maybe a bug in my head :-)?

```
public static bool IsValidUriHttp(string uriString)
        {
            Uri test = null;
            return Uri.TryCreate(uriString, UriKind.Absolute, out test);
        }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you see the [Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.scheme.aspx) then it says that:

> The Scheme property returns the scheme used to initialize the Uri instance. This property **does not indicate** that the scheme used to initialize the Uri instance was **recognized**.

So it just shows the scheme no matter if it was a known scheme or not.

Also the `Uri.TryCreate()` tries to create a Uri with any kind of scheme that it feels may be okay.

Like i tried this and see what i got:

```
Uri t = null;
Uri.TryCreate("rwr:dsffs",UriKind.Absolute, out t).Dump();
t.Dump();
```

[image]